admob banner ad edges not being blurred behind bottom navigation bar flutter
I want my bottom navigation bar to have blurry transluscent effect when scrolling, all items blur behind navigation bar but edges of banner ad doesn't. Contents of banner it being blurred but edges aren't.
I tried giving padding, wrap it inside a Card, but it still has sharp edges behind navigation bar.
Here is my bottom navigation bar:
Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 246, 246, 246),
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: ClipRRect(
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 20, sigmaY: 20),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.transparent,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
        centerTitle: false,
        title: const Text("My app"),
      ),
      extendBody: true,
      bottomNavigationBar: ClipRRect(
        child: BackdropFilter(
          filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 20, sigmaY: 20),
          child: NavigationBar(
            destinations: const [
              NavigationDestination(
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.home),
                icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.work_history_rounded),
                icon: Icon(Icons.work_history_outlined),
                label: 'My suitcase',
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle_outlined),
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
                label: 'Profile',
              ),
            ],
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _onItemTapped(index);
              });
            },
            backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(0, 255, 255, 255),
            elevation: 0,
            indicatorColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 132, 170, 198),
            selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: IndexedStack(
        index: _selectedIndex,
        children: [
          RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: _handleRefresh,
            child: homeList(),
          ),
          RefreshIndicator(
            onRefresh: _handleRefreshMySuitcases,
            child: mySuitcaseList
          ),
          Profilepage(context.read<SharedData>().User),
        ],
      ),
    );

here is my list view in homeList:
ListView.builder(
  controller: scrollController,
  itemCount: homeItems.length +
      (homeItems.length ~/ 5),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    int actualIndex = index - (index ~/ 6);
    if ((index + 1) % 6 == 0) {
      return const BannerAdWidget();
    } else {
      return HomeItem();
    }
  },
),

The problem is only on ios device (actual device and iphone simulator), the edges of ad banner is blurred in both android emulator and actual android device as intended

